# While loop displays one record multiple times php and mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from the database. But while loop is executing and displaying data multiple times. Please see the screen shot

[image]

```html
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","midata");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC"; 
?>
<div class="modal-body">
<form>
    <?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        $name= $row['campaign_name'];
        $issues= $row['issue_name'];
        $ename= $row['unused_elements'];
        $uquantity= $row['unused_number'];
        $descript= $row['experience']; ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Campaign Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" value="<?php echo  $row['campaign_name'];?>">  
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Issues:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" value="<?php echo $row['issue_name'];?>"> 
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Element Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" class="col-md-6" value="<?php echo $row['unused_elements'];?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Unused Quantity:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" class="col-md-6" value="<?php echo $row['unused_number'];?>"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Description:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control  c-square" id="message-text" value="<?php echo $row['experience'];?>"></textarea>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Do let me know what needs to be done

Comment: show your  `mysql` `query`

Comment: <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","midata");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

Comment: Yes `your query fetching all the record` from `table` that's why your getting `more record` .

Comment: ok . I will remove * then

Comment: you misunderstand `*` is used for fetch the all `column` from table  . not for all the `rows` .i believe that you know the difference between `rows` and `columns`  If you want `limit the row` you can do that in `two` way **1st:** you can apply any `where` `clause` in query **2nd :** simple you can apply the `limit 1`  at the end of query

Comment: after applying limit 1 , i am still getting same issue.

Comment: apply this query `SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: @JYoThI : I tried that. Nothing happend. Please see the screenshot

Comment: @user8380237 you have to use LIMIT. As follows : SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

Comment: Take look on my answer @user8380237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your table has more rows then you are expecting.

limit your query using this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC limit 1";
```

or try to fetch data using id or primary key.

or change your code with given below.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","midata");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC"; 
?>
<div class="modal-body">
<form>
    <?php 

        $name= "";
        $issues= "";
        $ename= "";
        $uquantity= "";
        $descript= ""; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        $name= $row['campaign_name'];
        $issues= $row['issue_name'];
        $ename= $row['unused_elements'];
        $uquantity= $row['unused_number'];
        $descript= $row['experience']; 


 } ?>
   <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Campaign Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" value="<?php echo  $row['campaign_name'];?>">  
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Issues:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" value="<?php echo $row['issue_name'];?>"> 
        </div>
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Element Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" class="col-md-6" value="<?php echo $row['unused_elements'];?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Unused Quantity:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control c-square" id="recipient-name" class="col-md-6" value="<?php echo $row['unused_number'];?>"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Description:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control  c-square" id="message-text" value="<?php echo $row['experience'];?>"></textarea>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked thanx but when I tried "SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; It didn't work. why?

Comment: did you check query in mysql or phpMyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to analyze the query result by directly running the mysql select query by terminal or phpmyadmin tool. Please check the result of the query with php code, If both are same your table contains duplication data.

Answer (score 0):

If want `show single record` means no need `while loop` just do it like below

Limit the `record` by adding `limit 1`

```
SELECT * FROM campaign_profile ORDER BY id DESC limit 1
```

**PHP :**

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 $name= $row['campaign_name'];
 $issues= $row['issue_name'];
 $ename= $row['unused_elements'];
 $uquantity= $row['unused_number'];
 $descript= $row['experience'];
```